# Show convexity of a set.

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Consider linear subset $H$ of a normed space $X$ such that there exists a $c > 0$ and $x_0 \in X$ with

$ \Vert x−x_0\Vert \ge c$ for all $x \in H$,

every $x \in X$ is represented  in the form $x = tx_0 + y$ with
$t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in H$.

Now I am supposed to show that this set is convex. I tried some attempts, but it didn't work out. I know that I need to verify for $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $x,y \in H$ that $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in H$.

Comment: Is $H$ a linear subspace? then it is convex (trivially). If $H$ is determined by the inequality, then $x_0=0$, $H=\{x: \|x\|\ge 1\}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @daw No, is only a subset. Isnt H a hyperplane? I thought hyperplanes are always convex.